# Connect local phpMyAdmin with remote server - error #2002

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, config, remote-access

I have been searching for a right answer and no luck with solutions. I have WampServer and phpMyAdmin on my localhost. I have created a user in phpmyadmin on remote server with all privilages.

- in folder wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/ I have found config.inc.php file

And tried to connect it to the remote databases with the following code:

```
<?php
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

$i++;
/* Authentication type */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypass';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'example.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
?>
```

And, as a result, in phpMyAdmin now I have 2nd server, but when I choose it - an error pops-up. MySQL error #2002 that looks like this:

## 2002 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Please help what am I missing!

Answer (score 2):

You are suffering from a failure of communication between your machine and the server. If it was permission, you wouldn't get a dead request, you would get the permission error.

- Make sure your domain is available (connect to the address and get an answer somehow);
- Make sure your firewall has the proper port open. This can be tricky since you can use one port for entering the server and a different port for the service. Make sure your firewall rule is correctly written in a way that it allows your machine to use an external port to find the right internal service.
- Use INCORRECT username and password. When you solve this #2002 error, you will get a #1045 access denied error. Then you'll know that you need to be worrying about permission and grant IP access.
- Make sure your local Wamp has sockets available for PhpMyAdmin to establish the connection.
- Make sure your remote MySQL allows remote connections

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 connections listed there so it will show 2 connections.

So for your current config the 2nd server listed is trying to connect to  "**example.com**" server if you are trying to connect to this server make sure you have allowed remote connection's set up, and account privileges also for remote access.

If your not trying to connect to "**example.com**" change these lines to the remote host you want to connect to.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypass';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'example.com';
```

You may need to add in port as well

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307'; // MySQL port
```

Comment: Yes - I want two connection, one for the localhost and one for my remote server. I have created a user in phpMyAdmin for remote server (example.com) with all privilages and I am using this username and password.
So, you think it is the issue of username/pass and privilages?
Just to add, that it is shared hosting that I want to connect with - so, millions of people succesfully did this :)

Comment: Yes it will be privileges, since phpmyadmin is connecting via mysql it needs the correct privileges set for remote access. as long as the account can connect remotely then these account details will work with phpmyadmin.

Comment: No luck with that - I have created a user on server with all privilages.

Comment: 1) check that MySQL is remotely listening sounds like its not after reading your error message, make sure the port is open firewall etc....
2) when giving privileges make sure your doing for the remote address 
eg
GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO lukesUbuntu@'192.168.1.110' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';

Comment: What do you mean by checking if remotely listening sound?
In cPanel I have grant host access (remote database) with my IP address.
I have grant all permissions for myself @myIPaddress identified by password. And still I got #2002.
Also, when I put port 3036 - it still doesn't work, and in Firewall I have opened that one.

Comment: @mpavlovic89 i do my mysql by config file i don't use cpanel sorry but check this out http://liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel Also you may have to add a extra $cfg line which i have appended in.
 
Also to make sure its not a local issue with the server running phpmyadmin you could test the remote connection with http://www.rainbowspuppiessunshine.com/tools/dbtest/